# Tooltip is not correctly positioned in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have modal and inside modal is a grid, so when I focus column, and then scroll down/up, bootstrap tooltip is scrollling too. What should I do to prevent that problem?

```
Code:
<th data-column-id="books" data-column-name="BOOKS" data-header-align="center" data-align="center" data-sortable="true" data-title="Sort by Book">Book</th>
```

Comment: You've tagged [tag:jquery-ui-tooltip] but stated *bootstrap tooltip* - these don't play nicely together, so which is it?  jquery-ui or bootstrap?   Please include the relevant code so we can see the problem in action: see [mcve].

Comment: I am using jquery.validate.bootstrap-tooltip.js @freedomn-m